# String works in InsertFile. Variable containing same string does not. Why?

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I am using Excel VBA 2016.  I have applied all available updates.

This works fine for me when I attempt to insert into a WORD document.

```
Range.InsertFile FileName:="c:\tmp\filename.rtf"
```

If I do this...

```
variable = "c:\tmp\filename.rtf"
Range.InsertFile FileName:=variable
```

It does not work.  The error message is, "Sorry, we couldn't find your file.  Was it moved, renamed, or deleted?"  Then it gives me the path in parenthesis.

I have unsuccessfully tried all sorts of permutations that might make this work and Googled for too long.  Any ideas?

Comment: Are you running this code from Excel or Word?

Comment: I'm running it in Excel

Comment: Then please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Yeah, good call.  I removed everything and it is working.  I'm adding back in and will report back the culprit.  Good advice.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a bug in VBA.  I was trying to read a list of RTF file names in a Word document I had generated from a different program.  Then I was going to insert the RTF back into the same Word document in a new table.  I tried both an array and an ArrayList.  Both failed.  Ultimately, I had to dump these file names into a text file and read it from there.  That worked perfectly.  Thanks Ahmed for making me do the hard word I was avoiding.  Hopefully this helps someone else.